# Stability problems with hostapd 0.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 running kernel 3.2.0-58-generic with TP Link WN822N

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, usb, hostapd

I am running hostapd 0.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 (kernel 3.2.0-58-generic) with two USB WLAN sticks. The first one is a D-Link DWL-G122 and it worked perfectly for a year to let the machine work as a soft AP. The second one is a TP Link WN822N (lsusb reports it as 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.) which should replace the D-Link DWL-G122, but with that one I have huge stability problems. When I use my notebook (Eee PC 1005HA, has a 802.11n-compatible chipset) as a client, it sometimes works without any problems, the other time I get regularly disauthenticated by hostapd if I don't run a non-stop ping in a console window, yet another time the connection just drops and I have to reconnect on my notebook. With my cell phone (Sony Xperia MT 15i, running kernel 2.6.32) as a client the situation is even worse: it authenticates at the hostapd-AP, gets an IP address and two seconds later it disconnects, authenticates again, gets an IP address again and so on.

My hostapd.conf file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/055yQZRS), the output of hostapd when my cell phone disconnects and connects continuously can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2SX7zZeT).

What I tried so far:

- Disconnecting and reconnecting the device via USB --> no effect
- Turning "wmm_enabled" to "0" --> no effect
- Channel 1 or 2 --> no effect
- Tried different combinations of "ht_capab", with some of them, hostapd didn't start at all
- Having eap_reauth_period set to 360000000 or not set at all --> no difference

Any hint how I could debug and/or solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

More about my configuration: The soft AP machine is connected via eth0 to the LAN and via eth1 to the Internet, the (old) DWL-G122 is named wlan0 and the (new) WN822N is wlan1. hostapd runs two times: one time for using wlan0 as an AP (actually as a daemon) and one time for using wlan1 as an AP (I start it manually via command line to see the output). I want to use my cell phone and my notebook as WLAN clients, they should authenticate against hostapd running on the machine used as a soft AP. This works with wlan0, but not with wlan1.

Best regards

Michael

Comment: I don't understand your configuration. You are running hostapd on your Eee, using the WN822N as the AP, is this right? Second: how do you connect to your LAN? Via ethernet? Via the DWL-G122? There is nothing in the files you posted that suggests whether you are bridging with eth0, or NATting with DWL-G122.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: Thank you for your feedback, I improved my question based on it. Is it clear now?